# Convert docker run command to docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to transform this docker run command to docker-compose.  Unfortunately I don’t know how to transform the last part of it.

**docker-run**

```
docker run \
    -p 6600:6600 \
    -p 6680:6680 \
    trestrantham/docker-mopidy-spotify \
    mopidy \
    -o spotify/username=USERNAME \
    -o spotify/password=PASSWORD \
    -o audio/output="lamemp3enc ! shout2send mount=mopidy ip=192.168.99.100 port=8000 password=mopidy"
```

Here is what I´ve got so far:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    mopidy:
        ports:
            - '6600:6600'
            - '6680:6680'
        image: trestrantham/docker-mopidy-spotify
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're only missing the command and env variables (you should fill in their values)

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    mopidy:
        ports:
            - '6600:6600'
            - '6680:6680'
        image: trestrantham/docker-mopidy-spotify
        environment:
            - USERNAME=___USERNAME___
            - PASSWORD=___PASSWORD___
        command: 'mopidy -o spotify/username=$USERNAME -o spotify/password=$PASSWORD -o audio/output="lamemp3enc ! shout2send mount=mopidy ip=192.168.99.100 port=8000 password=mopidy"'
```

Edit: added missing quotation mark

Comment: It is not recommended to specify such variables in files. If you don't have any CI/CD pipeline then you can run `export USERNAME=... && docker-compose ...` and replace a specific values with a $USERNAME and $PASSWORD variables.